# GetLogicalDriveStrings, why list of strings

Tags: c++, winapi

Do I understand correctly that this function returns drive letters?
If yes, then why does GetLogicalDriveStrings gives series of null-terminated strings and not series of chars?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it returns strings that can be used as input to functions like GetDriveType which require the input to be in the form "c:" not just 'c'.